# subgrouping with doxygen -> output to uml diagram gets duplicated

Tags: c++, documentation, uml, grouping, doxygen

Hei! I've got some code which I want to be documentated by doxygen. Therefore I'm interested in UML diagrams which worked fine - but now I want to use some subgrouping like this:

```
///@{
/// @name The lame constants
/// @details There are two seperate vectors for the first lame constant (in water and ground) but only one for the shear module (also known as second lame constant), since shear module for water is zero! Every element of the vector belongs to one grid point, linear interpolation within vertical direction will be applied. By using this the assumption of an isotrope media is made!
std::vector<double> lamw;           ///< first lame constant for the water area
std::vector<std::complex<double> > lamb;    ///< first lame constant for the area beyond the seabed
std::vector<double> mub;            ///< shear module (second lame constant) for the area beyond the seabed 
///@}
```

I want a subgroup within the "public member" group (since the variables are defined inside a class).

but what happened is this:

```
--------------------
| className        |
--------------------
| + lamw           |
| + lamb           |
| + mub            |
--------------------
| * lamw           |
| * lamb           |
| * mub            |
--------------------
```

The **variables are displayed twice**: in the member-variable-section as well as in the method-section. This of course is not that what I want to happen (the parts with the asterix are "to much")...

So doxygen seems to be confused with the subgrouping I used - did I made some mistake here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug.... It's unclear if it is a Won't Fix. The code makes no attempt to do anything other than append the member group items at the end of a class diagram.

https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=421218